# QGIS spatial sampling tool for existing points within a polygon ensuring even spread

Tags: qgis-2.18, random, sampling, point

I would like to spatially sample 10 existing points from within a polygon. I have read the answers from "QGIS point sampling tool really slow for polygons?"; "points within a polygon" as well as "How to randomly select from existing points within each polygon"

I would like the sample to ensure even spread across the entire polygon (i.e. I don't want 10 randomly sampled points within one corner of the polygon). I have tried 'vector - research tools - random selection', which does randomly select 10 points, but does not ensure even spread of the entire polygon.

Does QGIS have a tool that can do this?

Comment: If you want an even spread - then by definition that's not random?

Comment: Perhaps I could word it better. I'm looking for _spatial_ sampling. In some instances the points overlap each other. Instead of actively selecting points that are evenly spread across the polygon, I want to find out if there is a QGIS tool that can do it for me.